# How to find a number of consecutive rows in table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a booking system that can select consecutive seats in order. I have a table containing the following:

| ID | row | seat | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01 | 1 |
| 2 | A | 02 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 03 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 04 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 05 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 06 | 1 |
| 3 | B | 01 | 1 |
| 3 | B | 02 | 1 |
| 3 | B | 03 | 1 |

the table could contain many rows and many seats. I am trying to query the table to find x number of seats where the row is the same and the status = 1. I've tried the following query where x = 2 but get no results:

```
select seat, status from seats
where seat >= (
       select a.seat
       from seats a
          left join seats b on 
             a.seat < b.seat and
             b.seat < a.seat + 2 and
             b.status = 1
       where a.status = 1
       group by a.seat
       having count(b.seat)+1 = 2
       )
group by `row` limit 2;
```

Any ideas

Comment: some input data, and desired output might make your problem clear.   "I've tried the following query where x = 2"  You did not explain what `x` is in this equation (or I did miss that....(or it was not clear))

Comment: x in my sql is 2 but it could be 1 - 10 seats

Comment: You are not getting results, because the SQL is throwing an error see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9315a8813460fd7da86b0ae3a93bb8cf)   When (trying) to program in PHP/MySQL you should always enable error reporting on your development system. (see: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)).   Secondly, you should try to avoid using [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R) in  an SQL statement (LIKE `row`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query (given X = 3 in this case):

```sql
select 
  a.row, 
  a.seat, 
  group_concat(b.status order by b.seat) as status_seq 
from seats a 
inner join seats b on 
  a.row = b.row 
  and a.seat <= b.seat 
where a.status = 1 
group by a.row, a.seat 
having status_seq like '1,1,1%';
```

The X = 3 is represented by the number of '1' in the last pattern. You can use `concat(left(repeat('1,', 3), 3*2-1), '%')` instead of this string pattern to automatically produce it, where the two '3' are X.

The idea is, for every seat where `status` is `1`, to get the status of the next seats in the same row, including itself. This sequence is available through the `status_seq` value.
For instance, **if you set the status of seat A-03 to 0**, the status_seq of each available seat will be the following:

```
+------+------+-------------+
| row  | seat | status_seq  |
+------+------+-------------+
| A    | 01   | 1,1,0,1,1,1 |
| A    | 02   | 1,0,1,1,1   |
| A    | 04   | 1,1,1       |
| A    | 05   | 1,1         |
| A    | 06   | 1           |
| B    | 01   | 1,1,1       |
| B    | 02   | 1,1         |
| B    | 03   | 1           |
+------+------+-------------+
```

Then to get 3 consecutive seats, you just have to filter this result to get every row which sequence starts with '1,1,1', using the `having` filter.

This would give you the following result (remember that in this example, seat A-03 is not available):

```
+------+------+------------+
| row  | seat | status_seq |
+------+------+------------+
| A    | 04   | 1,1,1      |
| B    | 01   | 1,1,1      |
+------+------+------------+
```

With X = 2:

```
+------+------+-------------+
| row  | seat | status_seq  |
+------+------+-------------+
| A    | 01   | 1,1,0,1,1,1 |
| A    | 04   | 1,1,1       |
| A    | 05   | 1,1         |
| B    | 01   | 1,1,1       |
| B    | 02   | 1,1         |
+------+------+-------------+
```

Each row in the query result is the first seat of a sequence of X available seats. You can add a final `limit 1` if you want to get only the first one.